# Good reference for x86 assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking for a good reference for x86 assembly instructions with all the information about the instructions like the opcode, size etc.

Comment: intel.com or amd.com seem a good starting point, any particular generation of instruction set?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if someone could point to a reference for  8086 instruction set.

Comment: It doesn't completely meet your standard so I'm posting this only as a comment, but wiki contributors have made a wonderful job here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

Comment: I can't believe that the powers-that-be voted this question so far up, instead of shooting it down because it is not a question that has a decent answer. X86 can be any of the 80x286 80x386 80486 myriad of Pentium. Then there are 64 bit extensions where AMD and Intel are fighting over mind share. At least one should choose between: give me an overview of this Pentium III instructions, of give me an overview of all instructions ever invented in the x86 families.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Intel Architecture Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), especially volume 1 (basic architecture) and volumes 2A and 2B (instruction set reference).

Comment: Can you please point to a quick reference which covers just the basic statements like add,sub, jmp etc.

Comment: @Bruce, depends on how simple you want it to be. Did you check the lists on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings)?

Comment: @Bruce: you want http://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/manual/253666.pdf and http://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/manual/253667.pdf for the instruction set details.

Answer (score 12):

Here is another: http://ref.x86asm.net/

Answer (score 8):

http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/

Generated from the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, volumes 2A and 2B.

Includes AVX version of SSE instructions.

More info at Github [zneak/x86doc](https://github.com/zneak/x86doc).