# What are the documents of reference for the X86 and ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, standards

In the C++ case there are the ISO papers and the "community" papers about drafts for future and present definition of the language.

What are the equivalent sources for the assembly for both X86 and ARM platform ?

I found really hard to keep up with assembly because it's really fragmented ( even considering only the X86 platform ) and in many case I can't even find out what a register X refers to, or what CPU set suppports that feature or register.

There isn't an index of all the registers, isn't it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good reference for x86 assembly instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568848/good-reference-for-x86-assembly-instructions). Each manufacturer documents their own chips.

Comment: If you want to equivalent of the ISO standards, lok at manufacturer documentation and manuels. For x86, look at the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer to your question is complicated because manufacturers produce manuals for their processors.  In addition x86 is furhter complicated because there are generally separate documentation manuals for 32 bit and 64 bit processors (I'm not familiar enough with ARM to comment here).

**Intel x86** (both 32 and 64 bit) can be found here: [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

**AMD x86** documents: [All processors](http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.1;2.12&product=&contentType=Tech%20Doc%20Processor) and [AMD64 Architecture
and Software Manuals](http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.1%3b2.12&product=5.7&contentType=Tech+Doc+Processor&ostype=&keywords=&items=20).  There are a lot of resources here and you will probably need to filter it a little depending on exactly what you are looking for.

**ARM** makes reference manuals available by ARM architecture: [ARM Architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html)

Comment: I was surprised noticing that no one mentioned the OS as possible variant, but in reality sometimes I see assembly code signed as "linux only" or "windows only" os something like that: are those some low level kernel calls or something unrelated to the CPU and hardware register?

Comment: The interface to the OS differs (wildly!) between DOS, Windows, Linux, etc. It's more a question of "what do you do with assembly language" than assembly language itself (which has no "standards" like C, etc.). Every assembler is free to use their own syntax... and they do! What CPU? What assembler? What OS? You need to know all three to write assembly language.